# Is The SSL Padlock Required To Get An SEO Boost?

Tags: seo, https

So i have read that using SSL on a website gives a boost to SEO. I have picked up an SSL cert and installed it and its working, but the padlock doesnt display on every page.

The padlock in the URL bar does not appear on all pages. It displays on the login page, but for blog posts it does not. I ran a scan and this is down to links to insecure websites. Twitter, gravatar, adsense, jquery and many other common/trustworthy links are the cause.

Other than this the SSL does appear to be working. Do i need to have the padlock in order to get the SEO boost?

To explain better, https://blog.servertastic.com/wp-content/uploads/dubious-as-neutral.png. Some pages are secure HTTPS, but links to twitter, facebook etc are causing blog posts to have "HTTPS with minor errors"

Answer (score 1):

It used to be that SSL was very slow and one of the reasons it was recommended just for sensitive pages, as technology has got better SSL is less of a hinder and Google's stance on the matter is that all pages regardless of the content should be SSL. So to answer your question, yes your site should all be SEO enforced to leech the 'TINY' boost that SSL-Enabled sites receive.

*This can be done as simply as adding this to your .htaccess:*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. To be more specific, i have it setup already, but i want to know if the padlock is required. https://blog.servertastic.com/wp-content/uploads/dubious-as-neutral.png . I have https with minor errors.

Comment: That means that certain files or elements are loading over HTTP rather than HTTPS. search through the source when the page has rendered for all things `http://` then change it to `https://`.

Comment: im not sure this can be done though? these links are coming from googles adsense stuff which will use an iframe which i cant edit. does this cause the seo boost to be removed?

Comment: Adsense uses SSL... unless your using outdated code to load the javascript.